# How to index pdf files in apache solr?

Tags: tomcat, solr

I am working with apache solr with apache tomcat. I am trying to index pdf files in apache solr. But I am getting error as follows

```
collection1: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException:org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Schema Parsing Failed: Element type "field" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>".
```

Comment: Thanks  coding_idiot that issue solved.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have some syntax error in your `schema.xml` file. Please check if you haven't done any typo around some "field" declaration.